# Using an iFrame to get over same origin policy for AJAX calls

Tags: ajax, iframe, same-origin-policy

**Problem**:
A part of a web application contains another web application from another domain.
Both web applications make AJAX requests to the domains they originated from which poses problems because of the same origin policy for AJAX requests.

**Solution:**
One way to achieve this is to wrap the contained web application in an iFrame.  The AJAX requests in it go to the the same domain of the iFrame - which is different from the parent application.

This sounds fine to me, but since iFrames ae unfashionable, what other / better way is there to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Are you not able to have both applications send an AJAX request to your domain, and have your server side perform the call to a foreign domain, and then relay the result it receives back to the requesting client side App. Your server in essence becomes a proxy for the AJAX request?

Comment: Note a bad solution, but can't do it in this case.  The web application are actually from different companies.

Answer (score 0):

What do you men unfashionable? If you like to hind you can apply height to 0 and display none.